# Remove invisible null characters a string's ending

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, varchar

For an unknown reason, many strings in one of my VARCHAR(1000) columns have been terminated with invisible characters.

```
declare @BrokenString varbinary(max)=0x6D0079002000620075006700670065006400200073007400720069006E00670000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003F003F00;
select cast(@BrokenString as nvarchar(max)) -- returns 'my bugged string'
select cast(@BrokenString as nvarchar(max)) + ' is bugged' -- still returns 'my bugged string' !

declare @BrokenStringTable table (Brokey nvarchar(max));
insert into @BrokenStringTable
select cast(@BrokenString as nvarchar(max));
select * from @BrokenStringTable for json auto;
```

The output from the `select * from @BrokenStringTable for json auto;` statement looks like this :

```
[{"Brokey":"my bugged string\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000??"}]
```

How can I detect which records in my table contains these characters ? It seems using charindex, where+like and any other normal solutions just don't work with these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the reasons I vastly prefer `convert()` over `cast()` is that `convert()` is much more extensible. For example, you can use a style number to convert a binary value to a string *as is*. So if `3F00` is always the problematic character:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @BrokenString, 1) LIKE N'%3F00' 
  THEN 'borked' END;
```

Result:

```
borked
```

So you can find all the offending rows (this will not set any speed records) using:

```
SELECT ... FROM dbo.table 
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(max), column) LIKE N'%3F00';
```

Comment: Thanks I managed to detect them, off to clean them

Comment: I know it’s not necessarily related, by SQL Variants have a similar effect (except they break Windows). I wonder if you can use the same logic to make the invisible character show up

Answer (score 1):

After looking at Aaron's answer, I found a way to remove all of the 0x000 \u0000 null characters. This technique uses a bunch of converts as varchar(max) and as Aaron said won't set any speed records but it worked fine.

I wrapped it inside two functions so it ends up being used like this :

```
select BrokenStringColumn
,dbo.RemoveNullCharacters(BrokenStringColumn) 'FixedColumn'
from BrokenTable
where dbo.ContainsNullCharacters(BrokenStringColumn)=1
```

The `FixedColumn` will contain the entire string without the null characters which previously broke the correct display of my string.

Here is an example

```
declare @BadString nvarchar(max)= convert(nvarchar(max),0x6d0000007900) 
,@GoodString nvarchar(max)= convert(nvarchar(max),0x6d007900)
select @BadString 'badstring'                 -- result : 'm'
,@GoodString 'goodstring'                     -- result : 'my'
,@BadString+ 'test' 'failed_concat'           -- result : 'm'
,dbo.ContainsNullCharacters(@BadString) 'cb'  -- result : 1
,dbo.ContainsNullCharacters(@GoodString) 'cg' -- result : 0
,dbo.RemoveNullCharacters(@BadString)+' test' -- result : 'my test'
```

Here is the code for the functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].RemoveNullCharacters
(
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN convert(nvarchar(max),convert(varbinary(max),replace(convert(varbinary(max),@String),0x0000,0x)))
END
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].ContainsNullCharacters
(
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN case when CHARINDEX(0x0000,convert(varbinary(max),@String))>0 then 1 else 0 end
END
```

Comment: Simply looking for and deleting `0x0000` [may result in data corruption](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eb66dfda7500595e2c7e180524dbece6). I think the search needs to be a little more sophisticated.

Comment: Arggh. You're right https://i.imgur.com/2oIq2mm.png Now can I fix this

Comment: A 0x0000 sequence is a null character only if the position it's found at is an odd number. So the check function will be easy to fix. *Edit: actually no, it probably won't be, I was too optimistic there.* The removal function, not so much.